# Fortran Dot Product performance: Increasing cpu time consumption with diminishing array size

Tags: performance, fortran, dot-product, autocorrelation

this is more of a theoretical question on autocorrelation function and computer performance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation

(sorry not sure how to type equations on stack overflow)

The autocorrelation function is mostly just the dot product of an array shifted by a time (index).

Therefore, the autocorrelation uses the dot product of:

the original array from its initial index (0) to size - correlation_time index

x

and that original array from index(correlation_time) to size

Below is a simple picture of this sum of dot products. [Another Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn79U.png)

```
[1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x    |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

to

```
[1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
x                   |  |  |  | 
                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

From this, I believe that as you compute the autocorrelation for a large time, the dot product should clearly get smaller and should be easier to compute. Yet, the fortran code below says otherwise.

As correlation time increases and therefore arrays to be dot-producted are smaller, the computational time gets larger as the magnitude of correlation time increases!

What exactly am I missing here?

**acorr.f90**

```
PROGRAM acorr
    real:: a,b,c,d, sum
    integer:: i,j, jsize,beginning, rate, end
    real, dimension(2000000):: Jx, corr
    integer:: skip_lines = 4
    call system_clock(beginning, rate)
   
   !Reading file here
    open(10, file='data.log', status='old')
    do i = 1,skip_lines
        read(10,*)
    end do
    do i = 1, 2000000
        read(10,*) Jx(i)
    end do
    call system_clock(end)
    print *, "elapsed time for reading: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
    close(10)
    jsize = size(Jx)
    print *, "Size of Jx: ", jsize
    call system_clock(end)
    !End of reading file

    !begin dot product for autocorrelation
    print *, "Loop Start Time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
    do i =1,jsize
        a = dot_product(Jx(i:jsize),Jx(1:jsize-(i-1)))
        if(i == 1) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e0 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)

        else if(i == 10) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e1 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)


        else if(i == 100) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e2 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)

        else if(i == 1000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e3 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 10000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e4 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 100000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e5 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
        else if(i == 1000000) then
            call system_clock(end)
            print *, "correlation time magnitude 1e6 elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)


        end if 

    end do
    call system_clock(end)
    print *, "elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
END PROGRAM
```

**OUTPUT**

```
elapsed time for reading:    4.67100000    
 Size of Jx:      2000000
 Loop Start Time:    4.67100000    
 correlation time magnitude 1e0 elapsed time:    4.67299986    
 correlation time magnitude 1e1 elapsed time:    4.69500017    
 correlation time magnitude 1e2 elapsed time:    4.90100002    
 correlation time magnitude 1e3 elapsed time:    6.93699980    
 correlation time magnitude 1e4 elapsed time:    27.3729992    
 correlation time magnitude 1e5 elapsed time:    227.809006 
 correlation time magnitude 1e6 elapsed time:    1704.59399    
 elapsed time:    2249.08105
```

Note: I have a data file with 2,000,0000 time points.

Compilation:
gfortran -o acorr.exe acorr.f90

System: Ubuntu Linux 20.04

**EDIT**
I just changed the dot product line to just do the dot product of the whole array

```
a = dot_product(Jx,Jx)
```

Results are still the same and it's taking longer as the loop index increases.

**EDIT 2**

Looks like I was not understanding my output correctly.
I added the following in the loop:

```
    a = dot_product(Jx(i:jsize),Jx(1:jsize-(i-1)))
    a = 0
    call system_clock(end)
    write(20,*) real(end - end1) / real(rate)
```

And looks like the output is just 1ms every loop. Which is approximately the time it takes for a single dot_product of a full vector. So I believe it is working as intended. The original outputs are supposed to be interpreted in log scale since clearly it takes more iterations to get from 10,000 to 20,000 than from 100 to 200.

Comment: You may have missed quite a bit, but we don't know because you didn't tell about the computation environment.  What operating system? What compiler flags?  Did you use the option ot use BLAS for the dot product?  In additional, the use of array sections as actual arguments may cause the compiler to use temporary variables.

Comment: Updated with notes at the end. Even if the array sections using temporary variables that doesn't change the fact that as the arrays get smaller the dot product should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was not understanding my output correctly. I added the following in the loop:

```
a = dot_product(Jx(i:jsize),Jx(1:jsize-(i-1)))
a = 0
call system_clock(end)
write(20,*) real(end - end1) / real(rate)
```

And looks like the output is just 1ms every loop. Which is approximately the time it takes for a single dot_product of a full vector. So I believe it is working as intended. The original outputs are supposed to be interpreted in log scale since clearly it takes more iterations to get from 10,000 to 20,000 than from 100 to 200.